# Can I get a list of previously opened files from 2 days ago?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I need to know if there's a way of see which files were edited in the last 2 days using aptana studio. I've been trying with google but not luck so far.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean getting that list programmatically? Because if not, then the question does not belong to Stackoverflow. (Maybe http://superuser.com ?)

Comment: Yes programmatically, is for an sh report script, but I can't even find this list in the ide or in any file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your files under version control ?

Using Git, it's easy to track changes with the following commands :

```
git diff ...
```

or

```
git whatchanged --since '11/10/2012' --until '11/12/2012'
```